# Upwork api public profile details

Tags: api

Can some one provide an example of how the upwork api response looks like for the profile details request (GET /api/profiles/v1/providers/{profile_key}.{format})? In particular, I want to know how the field 'tsexam' looks like.

The official website just mentions "tsexam:Describes a test that the freelancer has taken and made public." but I could not find an example how it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a real life example (my own test results):

```
"tsexams": {
    "tsexam": [
        {
            "ts_id": "12484009",
            "ts_score": "5.0000000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "6",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_name_raw": "Twitter Bootstrap",
            "ts_when": "05/25/2015",
            "ts_percentile": "100"
        },
        {
            "ts_score": "5.0000000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "1",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_id": "13854135",
            "ts_name_raw": "Upwork Readiness Test for Independent Contractors and Company Managers",
            "ts_when": "02/07/2016",
            "ts_percentile": "81"
        },
        {
            "ts_score": "4.8500000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "9",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_id": "12484200",
            "ts_percentile": "97",
            "ts_name_raw": "CSS",
            "ts_when": "05/25/2015"
        },
        {
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_score": "4.6500000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "18",
            "ts_id": "12483848",
            "ts_name_raw": "HTML5",
            "ts_when": "05/25/2015",
            "ts_percentile": "93"
        },
        {
            "ts_score": "4.2500000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "17",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_id": "13447578",
            "ts_percentile": "92",
            "ts_name_raw": "XHTML 1.0",
            "ts_when": "11/30/2015"
        },
        {
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_duration": "14",
            "ts_score": "4.4000000000000000",
            "ts_id": "12487175",
            "ts_when": "05/26/2015",
            "ts_name_raw": "U.S. English Basic Skills",
            "ts_percentile": "90"
        },
        {
            "ts_percentile": "88",
            "ts_name_raw": "WordPress",
            "ts_when": "06/19/2015",
            "ts_duration": "21",
            "ts_score": "4.4000000000000000",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_id": "12579622"
        },
        {
            "ts_when": "05/26/2015",
            "ts_name_raw": "Javascript",
            "ts_percentile": "84",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_score": "4.2000000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "31",
            "ts_id": "12486703"
        },
        {
            "ts_score": "3.8000000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "28",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_id": "13447443",
            "ts_name_raw": "PHP",
            "ts_when": "11/30/2015",
            "ts_percentile": "76"
        },
        {
            "ts_score": "3.7500000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "17",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_id": "12487102",
            "ts_name_raw": "Android Programming",
            "ts_when": "05/26/2015",
            "ts_percentile": "75"
        },
        {
            "ts_percentile": "74",
            "ts_when": "12/26/2015",
            "ts_name_raw": "AJAX",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_score": "3.7500000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "15",
            "ts_id": "13588155"
        },
        {
            "ts_score": "3.6500000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "36",
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_id": "12483180",
            "ts_name_raw": "jQuery",
            "ts_when": "05/25/2015",
            "ts_percentile": "73"
        },
        {
            "ts_percentile": "66",
            "ts_name_raw": "Joomla",
            "ts_when": "05/26/2015",
            "ts_id": "12487037",
            "ts_duration": "21",
            "ts_score": "3.3000000000000000",
            "ts_pass": "1"
        },
        {
            "ts_pass": "1",
            "ts_score": "3.0000000000000000",
            "ts_duration": "28",
            "ts_id": "12486319",
            "ts_percentile": "60",
            "ts_when": "05/26/2015",
            "ts_name_raw": "MySQL"
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!